# Nginx fastcgi django directory index of [folder] is forbidden

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying use Nginx to reversely proxy django via fastcgi.
And I come across a very weird problem:

Accessing http://{localhost}:8888/admin/ is correct.
But http://{localhost}:8888/staticexample/ is 403 forbidden.
(I googled some, and run the command chmod -R 775 staticexample).

(staticexample is just a view use temple and static resources)

The configurations are paste bellow, please kindly help or give suggestion.

django.conf >>>>

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 8888;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    charset utf-8;

location / {
    fastcgi_pass django;
    #include fastcgi_params; # double admin
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf >>>>

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    include django.conf;
}
```

Thanks & Regards,

Yaoyu

Project's urls.py>>>>>

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'learning.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^staticexample/', include('staticexample.urls')),
)
```

Staticexample app's urls.py>>>>

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^upload$', views.upload, name='upload'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

Project and app's urls.py are added.

Comment: Since every url is passed to Django, the error is there, not in nginx. What is your URLs.py?

Comment: @Melvyn, I added the project and app urls.py content, could you please help to check further, thanks a lot.

Comment: Clearly your issue is within Django. Your index view is returning the 403, perhaps it's decorated with a login protector. There's also the possibility your fastcgi config is off. I would reformulate the question as a Django problem, with focus on your view.